# How many IP numbers are there for a SQL server active active cluster setup also a active passive setup?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

How many IP numbers are required for a SQL server active/ active cluster setup also what in the case of an active/ passive setup?
Correct me if I am wrong
2 for private network
2 for public network ......
1 for virtual server IP
1 for SAN
1 for MSdtc

Comment: SQL Server setup requires its IPs and then you have requirements for Windows Cluster setup. The documentation for both is well documented on MSDN and TechNet.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct

For Multi Instance SQL Cluster (active/active )

1 IP for Windows Cluster

2 IP for SQL Server Virtual Network Name (SQL instance on each node)

1 IP for MSDTC (this is optional however required if you use distributed transaction like linked server)

2 IP for public network (1 per node)

2 IP for heartbeat network (1 per node)

for Single Instance single cluster ( active/passive)

in above instead of two you will only need one IP address for SQL Server virtual network name